Calculate age of active employees
enter image description hereI need to calculate age of active employees in company. But on graph it show me minus age
active_employees = df[df['EmploymentStatus'] == 'Active'].copy()
current_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-09-27')
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'],format='%m/%d/%y')

active_employees['Age'] = current_date.year - active_employees['DOB'].dt.year
age_range = range(active_employees['Age'].min(), active_employees['Age'].max() + 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(active_employees['Age'], bins=age_range, color='skyblue', edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Wiek')
plt.ylabel('Częstotliwość')
plt.title('Rozkład wieku aktywnych pracowników')
plt.xticks(age_range)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


The duplicate shows how to correctly set discrete bins.

make sure there are no negative age in your input data,
active_employees = active_employees[active_employees['Age'] >= 0]

I also suggest updating your Pandas version to 2.2.2 or higher. you can check your Pandas version using the following command;
print(pd. __version__)

If this did not work, provide more info.

Pandas version is 2.2.2.

'active_employees = active_employees[active_employees['Age'] >= 0]' shows age correctly but its not a finish yet. I have a database where people were born in 54' so now they should have 64 years. But in graph the oldest persons have 49 years old.

What does pandas version have to do with anything?

In the older version it seems some old dates would be shown as NAT, I answered a question on SO on this which is now deleted tho.
